# Error on package and R paths and installations

Tags: r, ubuntu, package

I messed up my R installation while trying to move packages from the root to the user account. I tried unistalling (with --purge) and re-installing R (r-base r-base-dev) via the apt-get install. But I get the error

```
/usr/bin/R: line 236: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/R: line 259: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problems as yours and get it fixed by using this instraction after the uninstallation:

```
dpkg -l |grep ^rc|awk '{print $2}' |sudo xargs dpkg -P
```

and the previous configurations of R would be deleted. Then R can be installed perfectly.

Comment: So, before installation, this above should be run and then `sudo apt-get install r-base` ??