# Shiny error: "/usr/bin/R: line 238: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: Permission denied"

Tags: r, shiny-server

everything worked fine. I have R, R-Studio-Server and Shiny-Server running on a server.

I just updated the system (or do not remember what else I did) and accidentally broke shiny-server.
No matter which app I want to run it always gives me the Error:

> An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> The application exited during initialization.
>
> /usr/bin/R: line 238: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths:
> Permission denied ERROR: R_HOME ('/usr/lib/R') not found

For me it looks like a permission problem. But why does it pop up now and not before?

As everything worked fine before, I reinstalled: R, the shiny package and shiny-server (3x times). But did not succeed.
Because I think it also could be linked with the shiny user, I first removed the shiny user with:

```
deluser --remove-home shiny
```

I uninstalled R with:

```
apt-get --purge remove r-base-core
dpkg -l |grep ^rc|awk '{print $2}' |sudo xargs dpkg -P
```

(or 2nd cmd see: [Error on package and R paths and installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967256/error-on-package-and-r-paths-and-installations))

I deleted the shiny-server

```
apt-get remove shiny-server
```

rebooted and installed everything again.
Nothing works.
If I switch to shiny user it is also not possible to call R:

```
root@calculator:~# su shiny
shiny@calculator:/root$ R
/usr/bin/R: line 238: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: Permission denied
ERROR: R_HOME ('/usr/lib/R') not found
```

What could be the reason for this problem?

edit:

In case it is important:

> lsb_release -a
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
> Release:        14.04
> Codename:       trusty

I installed R 3.2.1
and the latest shiny-server with the provided code lines.

Thanks and best regards

Nico

Comment: some permissions changed. a few strategic chmod and chown commands should fix it.

Comment: "strategic" is a nice word - which folder permissions?
This folder "/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths" is kind of strange I can not really find it (only a link)
And why does a plain installation does not work proper without permission changes any more?
All other user do not have any trouble. Perhaps there is a more elegant way and just change the user that shiny uses.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/R`  and `ls -l /usr/lib |awk '{print $9}' |grep ^R$` ?

Comment: for the first cmd it is: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8712 Jul  5 17:32 /usr/bin/R`
last dir is marked green and 
the other cmd gives me a red marked `R`

Comment: I solved the problem. As I mentioned before a very simple way could be to change the user that shiny uses from "shiny" to "someotheruser". That's possible in the shiny-server.conf - BUT that is just a workaround I am STILL interested in the reasons for the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what worked for me. Open the terminal and switch to the root user.

```
sudo su
chmod o+r /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths
```

After that my apps started working again.